# Unable to deploy WinJS apps

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm working on a WinJS app which works perfectly on one particular Windows 8 image, but will not deploy on another that we use.

Attempting to run any WinJS project from visual studio results in the following error:

```
Error      1              Error : DEP0800 : The required framework 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.WinJS.1.0\1.0
\Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.appx" failed to install. 
Deployment Add operation on Package Microsoft.WinJS.1.0_1.0.9200.20602_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
from:  ([path])  failed with error 0x8007065E. See ]link] for help diagnosing app deployment 
issues.
```

Attempting to sideload the app doesn't work either, producing a similar error about the WinJS dependency not being resolved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the package identifier in the manifest and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the application already on the machine?  When updating an existing application, I've run into this a few times and first uninstalling from the target machine and then deploying from VS works.

Comment: Nope, it's not installed. I'm starting to think it has something to do with the group policy on the machine

Comment: does opening vs project on target machine show any warnings -- that winjs lib version is mismatching with what is on the target machine?

Comment: Nope, no warnings. It actually builds OK, it's the deploy step where it breaks. I've tried reinstalling the Winjs sdk too